# Connect to Remote Django Server

Tags: python, django, ssh

I have a remote virtual server running debian that I SSH into. On it I have a django server running using the standard manage.py runserver function. I have the IP address and root access. Is it possible for me to remotely access the server from another computer via a web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

`0.0.0.0` tells it to bind on the IP address of the server, which you can access from any other computer on the same network or the internet at large.